# No such file or directory error after compiling C program

Tags: c

I am just beginning in C, and I am using Code::Blocks and the GNU GCC compiler. I just created a new project, and tried to run the main.c file.

I then got this error after building and running:

```
sh: /Users/myname/Documents/c: No such file or directory
```

The message from the build log:

```
Checking for existence: /Users/myname/Documents/c tut/learning/bin/Debug/learning
Executing: osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"' -e 'activate' -e 'do script "/Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/myname/Documents/c\ tut/learning/bin/Debug/learning "' -e 'end tell'  (in /Users/myname/Documents/c tut/learning/.)
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
```

Any suggestions as to why?

Comment: Is your program supposed to be called "c"?

Comment: Where's the command you used to compile it?

Comment: It isn't called 'c', it is called "learning".

Comment: It's the build and run command in Code Blocks

Comment: Any way to figure out what gcc command line the Code Blocks generated when you tried to build it?

Comment: I'm on Mac OS X 10.7.5, programming in the Code Blocks IDE, but the output is in the command terminal. Sorry, I am very new to programming.

Comment: Q: After you typed in some C code ... did you "Save as" to some file?  Normally, it would be a filename like `hello.c`, or `myprog.c`.

Comment: yes, I did. the program is called main.c it seems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To try to compile a simple program with gcc and run it, type this at the bash prompt in a terminal window:

```
cat > myprog.c
main() {
    printf("Hello world!\n");
}
^d
gcc -o myprog myprog.c
./myprog
```

*Note "^d" means press the CTRL key + the D key at the same time*

Comment: Wouldn't hurt if you can get something working on the command line, even a small 'hello world' program to be sure things are working as expected in your environment. I don't know what "Code Blocks" is, but if it is an IDE you should check all the configuration settings, and know where its build targets and output are so you can find things, etc... And you should be able to find out what command it used to compile your code so you can figure out what it's doing wrong, if anything.

Comment: Would you mind giving me what I should type in the command line, I am still a but confused

Comment: @quantum_bro , Read this answer to know that.

Comment: What OS are you using first of all? What kind of command line shell? You diid mention gcc.  You create the program somewhere on disk that you know the path to and name it somename.c, then gcc -o somename somename.c and it should create an executable file called somename

Comment: When I do those lines, I get another no such file or directory error in the terminal

Comment: I will update my answer to show you exactly what to try in the terminal (bash shell) window.

Comment: do i just copy and paste that? or do it line by line?

Comment: Are you serious or are you trolling?  Do it line by line, because you have to press control+d  keys to send an EOF (end of file to the cat command) you can't type "^d"

Comment: I am really serious, I am very new to programming and I am just trying to get some help. I know I seem pretty dumb, but I could really use the help

Comment: OK for all this effort, please up vote my answer when we're done.  Look at my answer again. Type it in exactly as shown line by line. When you get to the ^d, that means press two keys together (don't type ^d), the rest of it just type. At the end it should print "Hello World"

Comment: Okay, it did work in the terminal, but when i went back to the Code Blocks compiler it didnt work

Comment: That's OK, thanks for accepting the answer. So I don't know much about Code Blocks so I can't be of help. But what I showed you is what Code Blocks should end up doing. Name your program with a .c extension. And you'll have to check out the configuration parameters and how your development environment works. Not much I can do to help you with that.